# ARMSIM sum to stdout

Tags: assembly, arm

Alter this first program so that, instead of doing the calculation from class, the program accesses the numbers a to e as if they are a 5 element array. Your program should:

Double each value in the "array" (store it back into memory at appropriate place)
Sum up the doubled values and store the sum back into x.
Output the resulting sum to stdout with an appropriate label.

I am having trouble with outputting the sum into x, everytime i try i end up getting no answer as a result.

```
  @ Our first ARM program
        @ x = e + ((a + b) - (c - d))
        @ Written by 210 class

        .data
        .align  2
a:      .word   4
b:      .word   5 
c:      .word   6
d:      .word   7 
e:      .word   10
x:      .word   0
answr:  .asciiz "Answer is: "

@--------------------------------------------------------
        .text
        .globl  _start
_start:  ldr   r0, =a       @ load address of a into r0
         ldr   r1,[r0]      @ load value of a into r1    
         ldr   r2,[r0,#4]   @ load value of b into r2
         ldr   r3,[r0,#8]   @ load value of c into r3
         ldr   r4,[r0,#12]  @ load value of d into r4
         ldr   r5,[r0,#16]  @ load value of e into r5
         add   r1,r1,r1     @ add a to itself
         add   r2,r2,r2     @ add b to itself
         add   r3,r3,r3     @ add c to itself 
         add   r4,r4,r4     @ add d to itself 
         add   r5,r5,r5     @ add e to itself
         str   r1,[r0]      @ store value of a into r1
         str   r2,[r0]      @ store value of b into r2 
         str   r3,[r0]      @ store value of c into r3
         str   r4,[r0]      @ store value of d into r4
         str   r5,[r0]      @ store value of e into r5
         add   r6,r1,r2     @ r6 holds a+b
         sub   r7,r3,r4     @ r7 holds c-d
         sub   r8,r6,r7     @ r8 holds (a+b)-(c-d)
         add   r9,r8,r5     @ r9 holds e+(a+b)-(c-d)
         str   r9,[r0,#20]  @ store result (in r9) into address of x
         mov   r1, r9    /   @ copy result into r1 to set up printing

        ldr     r0, =answr  @ put address of char string into r0 to set u printing
        swi     0x02        @ print character string

        mov     r0,#1     @ put 1 into r0 to indicate print to stdout
        @ r1 holds result
        swi     0x6b        @ print integer
    @----------------- Usual stuff at end of main ---------------------
    swi 0x11        @ halt//
```

Comment: What exactly does "getting no answer as a result" mean?  Are any characters written anywhere?  Does `swi 0x6b` really take a binary integer from `r1` and convert it to a string for you?  (There aren't any Unix or Windows system calls that do that (only library functions), but a toy/simulated learning system like ARMSIM could well do that.  So it might be right, but if nothing is printed that's the first question that comes to my mind.)

Answer (score 1):

The store instructions like `str   r2,[r0]      @ store value of b into r2` are obviously wrong.

`b+b` is already in r2, so the comment is wrong (copy/pasted from the load, I guess).

More importantly, you forget the offsets for the different array elements, so you're storing all the values into the first element of the array.

I don't know ARMSIM system calls, so IDK what you're doing wrong printing the sum.  Have you tried single-stepping in a debugger to make sure the first `swi` doesn't clobber `r1`?  If it doesn't, you should

```
     add   r1,r8,r5     @ r9 holds e+(a+b)-(c-d)
     str   r1,[r0,#20]  @ store result (in r9) into address of x
```

So then you don't need `mov   r1, r9`, because you generated the result in the register you want it in in the first place.

If it does clobber r1, you should leave `r8` and `r5` alone and move the add+store instructions (or the whole calculation) until after you print the fixed string.

Comment: so I should be storing them into memor so would it be r4,[#12]?

Comment: and also based on the instructions shouldnt my answer from this equation be double the original equation correct?

Comment: @naomigebremariam: Yes, if you want to put them back into the original locations.  `r0` hasn't changed, so the same offset will give you the same location as it did in the load.

Comment: @naomigebremariam: It looks like the assignment is telling you to forget the `x = e + ((a + b) - (c - d))` formula, and instead calculate `x = 2a+2b+...`.  You're doing the right thing by using the values that you still have in registers (the you also stored), but simply add them all up.